# How to allow no suffix in url pattern in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

Using the configuration below, I have to append ".html" to any URL pattern for it to be mapped to the appropriate controller. How do I configure Thymeleaf to also allow patterns such as `"/Main"`, instead of only `"/Main.html"` ?

```
  <bean id="webTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by an improper URL-pattern configuration for the Dispatch Servlet in spring.  It was configured to only accept .html. It was not a Thymeleaf issue.